# Tkinter, como utilizar o mesmo script no win e no llinux sem que o icone da janela atrapalhe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Venho escrevendo alguns *scripts* no VS do Win e quando mudei para o Linux, me deparei com o seguinte problema: Quando uso uma imagem como ícone da janela no Linux (que não possui o mesmo), o script não executa.

Como eu poderia "detectar" o OS para que ele não use esse recurso em distribuições Linux, evitando o erro?

Exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.title("teste")
#problema - mas e no Linux?
win.iconbitmap("logo.ico")

winLabel = Label(win, text="Isso é um teste").place(x=50, y=50)
win.resizable(width=False, height=False)
win.geometry("200x200")
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar o tratamento de exceções substituindo:

```
win.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
```

por:

```
try:
    win.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
except:
    pass
```